# Exceptions generated inside protected classes of Smack library

Tags: android, xml, smack, firebase-cloud-messaging, xmlpullparser

I am trying to establish a connection with Smack to Firebase Cloud Messaging CCS.
I am having problems with the following protected Smack Interfaces. I dont know exactly why are these interfaces being called for?

See below how I establish my configuration builder object and my connection:

```
configBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
configBuilder.setServiceName("192.168.1.74").setHost("fcm-  xmpp.googleapis.com").setUsernameAndPassword(s1, s2)              .setPort(5236).setSendPresence(false).setCompressionEnabled(false).setCustomSSLContext(contexty)
other_connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configBuilder.build());
//other_connection object is an AbstractXMPPConnection object
```

The android/smack code tries to connect but fails to do so. Here are the exceptions: Do note that my SSlcontext object has been initialized with keymanagerfactory that contains a key store who holds valid certificates validated by a certificate authority.

Exceptions:

```
**** Verification of void org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter.<init>(org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection) took 135.634ms*
07-29 03:30:14.211 3346-3408/rarigames.answerme V/RenderScript: 0xa172ca00 Launching thread(s), CPUs 2
07-29 03:30:39.281 3346-3548/rarigames.answerme D/ricky: Unable to connect or login to FCM CCS. org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 25000ms (~25s). Used filter: No filter used or filter was 'null'.
07-29 03:30:39.284 3346-3557/rarigames.answerme W/AbstractXMPPConnection: Connection closed with error
                                                                      org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT ��F@1:8 in java.io.BufferedReader@2c985591) 
                                                                          at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:432)
                                                                          at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:313)
                                                                          at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1169)
                                                                          at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$300(XMPPTCPConnection.java:948)
                                                                          at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:963)
                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

---

As you can see the Smack classes that are giving problems are:
protected class XMPPTCPConnection.PacketReader and
protected class XMPPTCPConnection.PacketWriter 
What is the Bufferedreader mentioned in the exception trying to read? An XML reply from FCM CCS? Should I authenticate this connection before trying to connect? Is that what is going on here that when I try to connect without authenticating the connection object is trying to authenticate itself and the XML packets are being sent to these protected classes of Smack library? How can I get these XML documents that are being possibly sent for authentication purposes, if they are really being sent by FCM CCS?

thanks for any advice or suggestion

Comment: Could you clarify where you are trying to connect to CCS from. It looks like you are trying to connect to CCS from the Android client which is not the way this was designed.

Comment: I have been able to connect to a FCM CCS. Turns out I was missing the SSLsocket. So all I did was use my SSLcontext to create an SSLsocket. Now the errors are gone, I am connected to FCM CCS. But now I am getting the following errors: incorrect encoding on X-OAUTH2. It seems the connection is trying to use SASLAuthentication using the Smack Library. I am trying to unregister SASLMechanisms and forcing the connection to only use SASLPlainMechanism which is the one that FCM CCS is asking for of android clients. Maybe, I should switch the order of how I am authenticating. @ArthurThompson

Comment: Where are you running the smack code from, your application server or the Android client?

Comment: Android client. @ArthurThompson

Comment: Why are you trying to connect to CCS from the Android client?

Comment: Well its working so far. Now i just to authenticate with SaslMechanism. @ArthurThompson

Comment: Your application will be insecure if you are connecting to CCS from your Android client. Your app can reveal your Server API key and once that is known anyone can send messages to your app. Please avoid using any client side code that requires you to include your Server API key.

Comment: I will store those credentials on online database

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that makes it secure, however another thing to consider is having an open connection to CCS will be very hard on the battery of the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay everyone:

All I was missing here to get rid of the errors was an SSLsocket object. Since, I don't know much about sockets and machine to machine connections, I had no clue. After much reading, I realized I was missing this object. Errors are gone now that the connection can flow between my Android code and FCM CCS. so I just added this method call to my configBuilder object:

```
 .setSocketFactory(contexty.getSocketFactory());
```

But, I am running into new errors that deal with SASLAuthentication using Smack. I will be posting a question on those errors soon. Seems I am getting closer to establishing a viable connection/login to FCM CCS.

Comment: I am getting MucConfigurationNotSupportedException In android smack 4.2.0-beta1 Do you know the solution? @i_o

Comment: I dont know about your exception. I've been dealing with exceptions in trying to establish a connection to FCM CCS. All I can tell you is that you should look into the javadocs for Smack in the following link: http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/  Read about the classes. I think your exception comes from the Multi User Chat format. Perhaps there's a class that deals with that. Read the docs. @MathaN I have been able to handle many exceptions by reading the methods and seeing how they interact with other Smack objects.